# How do I get schedule:run to work with systemd in a docker container?

Tags: docker, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, lumen, systemd

Following [this guide](https://www.euantorano.co.uk/posts/using-laravel-scheduled-tasks-with-systemd-timers/) I've set up two files

**/etc/systemd/system/lumen-cron.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Run lumen cron tasks
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/web/artisan schedule:run
```

and **/etc/systemd/system/lumen-cron.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Run lumen timed tasks

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnUnitActiveSec=1m

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I get my docker image `FROM ubuntu:xenial` and my start script has
`systemctl enable lumen-cron`

If I log in to the container however the scheduler is not running.

```
$ journalctl -f -u lumen-cron.timer
No journal files were found.

$ journalctl -f -u lumen-cron.service
No journal files were found.

$ systemctl list-timers
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I've hit a wall, I feel like I'm close. Has anyone else had success running laravel/lumen scheduler via systemd in a docker container?

Comment: You are setting up these files inside the container right?, Btw its better to use host system's cron to run scheduled tasks inside the containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to setup the `systemd` units inside the Docker container. While it is possible to use `systemd` inside containers, it is not a very common setup.

If you look at the output of `systemctl list-timers` above, you'll notice that it errors out with `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`. You are likely getting this error because you attempted to use `systemctl` inside a container where `systemd` is not running.

So, why is systemd not running in the container? Containers are by default isolated from the host in many ways. They have their own kernel namespaces, including their own PID 1. As a result, by default, your containers will not be able to use the host's `systemd` socket.

In order to use `systemd` in a container, you would need to run `systemd` as your container's PID 1. This would mean that you have two instances of `systemd`, one on the host and one in the container. RedHat has some [blog posts](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/) covering how to achieve this using Fedora images, however, as you'll notice, it requires some special care and its likely overkill for what you need.

Instead, here are some options that might help:

### Using the host's systemd:

This is probably the simplest solution. You could place these unit files in the host instead, and change the `ExecStart=` line so that it launches a new container with the same command:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run lumen cron tasks
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/docker run --rm -name lumen-cron yourdockerimage /usr/bin/php /var/www/web/artisan schedule:run
```

### Using a container orchestration platform:

If you have the time/resources to manage a cluster, using a platform such as [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) would be the ideal, specially if you would like to later scale this into more than one server.

Recent versions of Kubernetes have added support for [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) objects, which allow you to specify containers that are run periodically:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: lumen-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: lumen-cron
            image: yourimage
            args:
            - /usr/bin/php
            - /var/www/web/artisan
            - schedule:run
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

### Using `supervisord`:

If you just want to run everything inside a single container, you could use `supervisord` as PID 1 in your container, and have it run both your PHP/webserver and `crond`.

Comment: Used `supervisord`, after some fiddling it runs well. Thank you very much for your answer!